# In azure iot hub, do I need to explicitly copy reported properties into the device twin?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, arduino-esp8266

`properties.reported` in my device-twins are not updating.

I have a running project that follows this Azure IOT SDK tutorial (complete with same hardware):  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-arduino-huzzah-esp8266-get-started

D2C messages are being sent from device and acknowledged by azure.  I can monitor message arrival through **Device Explorer** and **iothub-explorer**, and I can see them accumulating in the table store, thanks to another tutorial I did to try to further prove messages were actually arriving.  However, the contents of the messages (reported properties) are not reflected in the device twin. **properties.reported** is empty except for the metadata timestamp from the day the device was registered.  Do I need to write an azure function to explicitly copy data from the message into the twin's reported properties?

FYI, C2D messages (`properties.desired` in the twin) are communicating just fine.

Comment: Where and how do you add these reported properties?

Comment: @Rita Han, down in the bowels of the tutorial code is a call to IoTHubMessage_CreateFromByteArray() which takes a JSON string as input. The result is later sent to IoTHubClient_LL_SendEventAsync(), and delivered during a call to IoTHubClient_LL_DoWork().  The messages arrive in hub and are logged (via function that merely copies them into azure storage table).  Example direct from the log:  `{"deviceId":"new-device","messageId":2,"temperature":22.29999,"humidity":47.2}
` ...and yes I have a registered deviceId of "new-device".

Answer (score 0):

Help arrived in another forum, so I'm adding the relevant details here.
The sample I linked above, and the other samples I tried, all were sending *events*, instead of properties, even though they were reading and reacting to (desired) properties sent from the cloud.  Reported properties must be sent with a call to IoTHubClient_LL_SendReportedState (C) or Client.UpdateReportedPropertiesAsync (C#).